# CPU does not support KVM but I want to run andriod emulator in AWS Linux instance

Tags: android-emulator, amazon-linux

I wanted to run headless android emulator on my EC2 instance - Amazon linux 2, but I am getting this error while executing **./emulator -avd my_avd_31 -no-audio -no-window**

```
emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
```

I tried adding hardware acceleration, kvm , virtualisation etc using different commands but it is not working.since almost all threads are using apt/apt-get i.e ubuntu distribution, I didn't find out anyone setting up hardware acceleration using yum, except one(yum install @virtualization), which is not working.
Please help me in this, stuck on this from past few hrs.
THanks